# Replicate Team foundation server project to another team foundation server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Currently I am working on a teamfoundationserver1. I want to replicate my project from teamfoundationserver1 to my local teamfoundationserver2. Please suggest me the steps to perform this action. I am novice in this so please suggest me a good article or step by step implementation of this.

Comment: What do you want to replicate? Source code, Work items, Reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion, based on what you've said you require would be:

1. Install [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f).
2. Map source directories for `teamfoundationserver1` and `teamfoundationserver2`.
3. Create the team project in `teamfoundationserver2`.
4. Check out a read-only copy of your team project from `teamfoundationserver1`.
5. Copy and paste in Windows Explorer over to `teamfoundationserver2`.
6. Right click the project folder, select `Team Foundation Server -> Add...`.
7. Answer the dialog questions and finish.

You should now have your team project listed as pending changes for `teamfoundationserver2`.

If you want to bring history across, too then have a look at [this](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).

Comment: He did say he wanted to replicate his project.  I forgot to mention salt!

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the help of TFSPowerTool I imported the template required.

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the team project collection from TFS1, backup the SQL database, re-attach the team project collection to TFS1, restore SQL database to the SQL server of TFS2 then attach the team project collection to TFS2