# Team Foundation Server replication

Tags: tfs

Tell me please. I can configure two TFS servers and replicate them. Thank you

> Blockquote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replicate Team foundation server project to another team foundation server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263379/replicate-team-foundation-server-project-to-another-team-foundation-server)

Comment: Sure. What have you tried? What problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that. TFS does not support replication. I remember only one system with replication: IBM Rational ClearQuest https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH5A_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.ms_admin.doc/topics/c_admin_db_replicas.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [Move a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-project-collection?view=tfs-2015) from one TFS to another.

1. Detach the collection from TFS 1
2. Back up the collection database
3. Move the collection database to TFS2
4. Attach the collection
5. Configure the moved team project collection
6. Configure projects

Comment: @Виталий Новиков Have resolved the issue? any update?